# Setting values to NA in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is some reproducible code that shows the problem I am trying to solve in another dataset. Suppose I have a dataframe `df` with some `NULL` values in it. I would like to replace these with `NA`s, as I attempt to do below. But when I print this, it comes out as `<NA>`. See the second dataframe, which comes is the dataframe I would like to produce from df, in which the `NA` is a regular old `NA` without the carrots.

```
> df = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,"NULL"),b=c(1,5,4,6))
> df[4,1] = NA
> print(df)
     a b
1    1 1
2    2 5
3    3 4
4 <NA> 6
> 
> d = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,NA),b=c(1,5,4,6))
> print(d)
   a b
1  1 1
2  2 5
3  3 4
4 NA 6
```

Comment: `"NULL"` and `NULL` are not the same thing. Typically you can't put `NULL` values in a `data.frame` - `data.frame(a=NULL,b=1)` fails for example. Your `df$a` is just a factor column with a label of `"NULL"` because you have put numbers and character strings together like `c(1,"NULL")`, which get coerced to a character vector, which then get coerced to a factor via `data.frame`'s `stringsAsFactors=` argument.

Comment: if you go `df$a <- as.integer(df$a)`, then look at `df`, you'll see your "NULL" has been coerced to NA (technically `NA_integer`)

Comment: @SymbolixAU but what if my data is not all integers.

Comment: then don't do `as.integer(df$a)`. I'm just highlighting the different **types** of `NA`, and that they're printed differently to the console

Comment: You should probably deal with this at the import stage. `read.table` `read.csv` etc have the option to define `na.strings=` which are "*na.strings: a character vector of strings which are to be interpreted as ‘NA’ values.*"

Comment: @thelatemail THANK YOU. very helpful.